# Comparing Adult Weights over time - Should I use 1 or 2 sample test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, two-sample

Background:
Many years ago, we were looking to calculate adult weights belonging to a certain population. At the time, it was assumed that the population mean was 77kg. After a survey, we got the following details:

Mean - 69kg, standard deviation - 19kg, sample size - 700 people.

Doing a hypothesis test with an alpha level of 5% made us reject the original hypothesis of mean weight = 77kg, and therefore we started using a mean of 69kg for future calculation.

About 5 years later, another survey was conducted to see if we needed to update our mean weight. The new results were:

Mean - 70.73kg, standard deviation - 14.16, and sample size - 561 people.

I want to know if I need to start using a new Mean weight for our calculations, or the previously determined weight of 69kg is satisfactory.

Question:

There's two ways I can go about this.

1. I have a null hypothesis that mean = 69kg. When I do a 95% confidence interval (Z->1.96) with the new survey numbers, it leads me to reject the null hypothesis. In this case I should update my mean weight to be 70.73kg for future calculations.
2. I do a two sample test [Mean1 69kg, std1 19kg, n 700 | Mean2 70.73kg, std 14.16, n 561]. If I do the math with a 95% confidence interval I fail to reject the null hypothesis. So for my calculations I would continue to use 69kg as my mean weight.

Is there a "correct" choice from the options above?